# Present a viewcontroller inside a navigationcontroller from another tab in tabbed application

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitabcontroller

I have a tabbed application and each tab has a navigation controller with table views in it.

In one of the view from a tab, I want to present the first view controller of another tab.

My `tabViewController.viewControllers` has an array of navigation controllers for each tab.

I cant seem to present the view controller directly without accessing the navigation controller and I guess you cant present a navigation controller. 
What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can access to your root controller something like that: `[[tabViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:0]`, but I dont think you can display one view twice. So you still should recreate this view controller to display it in another tab as childViewController, for example

Comment: `UINavigationController *mycont=    [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];          [self.tabBarController presentViewController:[mycont.viewControllers     objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES completion:nil];`

The above code throws error
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <UITabBarController: 0x715dba0>.'

Comment: Do I recreate the viewController and the navigation controller and then replace it in the `tabbarController.viewControllers` again? Am I correct in interpreting your answer?

Comment: I should have been clearer. I found what I was looking for, I should have just set the `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=index;` 
Thanks anyway.